# How to click a HTMLAnchorElementImpl from javafx

Tags: java, html, javafx, click

This [website](https://www.tsp.gov/InvestmentFunds/FundPerformance/index.html) contains the following html definitions:

```
<input class="startDateInput" id="startdate" name="startdate" type="text" value="09/21/2015" maxlength="10" size="10" onkeypress="return isDateKey(event)" onblur="if (this.value.length!=10) { this.value='09/21/2015'; }">
<a id="retrieve" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doSubmit('Retrieve')">Retrieve Share Prices</a>
```

With javafx, the start date field can be updated using

```
int startDateIndx = ...;
String newStartDate = ...;
String setStartDate  =  "document.getElementsByTagName('input')["
    +startDateIndx+"].value='" + newStartDate + "';";
webEngine.executeScript(setStartDate);
```

But, how to execute a click on "Retrieve Share Prices" element in java?

This attempt:

```
HTMLInputElement doRetrieve = (HTMLInputElement) doc.getElementById("retrieve");
doRetrieve.click();
```

generates this error:

```
com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLAnchorElementImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLInputElement
```

Here's a demonstration code

```
public class subForms extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private boolean notEmpty(String s) {
        return s != null && !"".equals(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final TextField fxUsername = new TextField();
        final TextField fxPassword = new PasswordField();
        final TextField fxStartDate = new TextField();

        final BooleanProperty loginAttempted = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> ov, Document oldDoc, Document doc) {
                if (doc != null && !loginAttempted.get()) {
                    if (doc.getElementsByTagName("input").getLength() > 0) {
                        int startDateIndx = getInputIndex(doc, "startdate");

                        if (startDateIndx >= 0) {
                            // webEngine.executeScript("window.coordinates.lat =
                            // 31.2;");
                            String newStartDate = fxStartDate.getText();
                            String setStartDate = "document.getElementsByTagName('input')[" + startDateIndx
                                    + "].value='" + newStartDate + "';";
                            loginAttempted.set(true);
                            webEngine.executeScript(setStartDate);
                            // com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLAnchorElementImpl cannot
                            // be cast to org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLInputElement
                            ((HTMLInputElement) doc.getElementById("retrieve")).click();

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            private int getInputIndex(Document doc, String matchName) {
                // matchName = "startdate"
                NodeList htmlInputs = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (int indx = 0; indx < htmlInputs.getLength(); indx++) {
                    Node inNode = htmlInputs.item(indx);
                    NamedNodeMap attributes = inNode.getAttributes();
                    // iterate over attributes
                    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
                        Attr attr = (Attr) attributes.item(i);
                        String attrName = attr.getNodeName();
                        if (attrName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                            String attrValue = attr.getNodeValue();
                            if (attrValue.equalsIgnoreCase(matchName)) {
                                return indx;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }
        });
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> ov, Throwable oldException, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println("Load Exception: " + exception);
            }
        });

        GridPane inputGrid = new GridPane();
        inputGrid.setHgap(10);
        inputGrid.setVgap(10);
        Button fxButton = null;
        fxStartDate.setText("3/3/2003");
        inputGrid.addRow(0, new Label("Start Date: "), fxStartDate);
        fxButton = new Button("Get TSP Share Price History");

        fxButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                if (notEmpty(fxStartDate.getText())) {
                    loginAttempted.set(false);
                    final String tspURL = "https://www.tsp.gov/InvestmentFunds/FundPerformance/index.html";
                    webEngine.load(tspURL);
                }
            }
        });

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Enter start date for TSP share price history"), 
                inputGrid, fxButton, webView);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Given the html, could you just call `webEngine.executeScript("doSubmit('Retrieve')");`? Or do you need something more general than that?

Comment: Great suggestion, can you add as an answer.  That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code you have posted, clicking on the link simply invokes the Javascript function `doSubmit('Retrieve')`. So, for this particular use case, you can achieve the effect you want by calling

```
webEngine.executeScript("doSubmit('Retrieve')");
```

This doesn't answer your actual question, though. I suspect with the correct downcast, forcing a click on the HTML element can be done; however the relevant DOM classes are not public API.

Comment: It appears that I asked the wrong question, and should have asked how to retrieve updated values, similar to clicking on "Retrieve Share Prices".  Thanks for seeing through the fog, and providing an appropriate answer.